# requery android - ambiguous method call for select

Tags: dao, rx-java2

Using [requery version 1.5.0](https://github.com/requery/requery) ReactiveEntityStore for select calls.

But the compiler giving error for below call -

```
Observable<Result<Person>> result = mDataStore
    .select(Person.class)
    .where(Person.CATEGORY.eq(category))
    .orderBy(Person.SEQUENCE.asc())
    .get()
    .observableResult();
```

Error details:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdPlY.png

Comment: Can you add more information about the type of `mDataStore`? Also, please don't link to external images with a screenshot with your error, but post the error as text here directly.

Comment: mDataStore is ReactiveEntityStore

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how you got that particular error message (maybe I can edit if you add more information about the actual classes involved).

However, it seems like you are mixing `Result` with `ReactiveResult`, what you want is probably:

```
// Supposing this is your definition of the data store:
ReactiveEntityStore<Person> mDataStore;

// Your result is going to be Reactive, next line is the one changed!
Observable<ReactiveResult<Person>> result = mDataStore
    .select(Person.class)
    .where(Person.CATEGORY.eq(category))
    .orderBy(Person.SEQUENCE.asc())
    .get()
    .observableResult();
```